# Unsupported Operation. A document processed by the JRC engine cannot be opened in the C++ stack windows app

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports-2010

I have created a C# windows application and after , and i have created my reports using crystal report .and it works fine ,
but now  i need to upgrade my interface , so i have created another c# windows application , after finishing my application screens i need my old reports to be embedded on my new interface application ,
what i did was r.click on my application \ add existing item \ selecting the .rpt files ,
but when try to run my application and open the report , application raise an exception "Load Report Failed " . 
The Inner Exception was "Unsupported Operation. A document processed by the JRC engine cannot be opened in the C++ stack" .
I have check these solutions :

1. report file path
2. rpt file property :  Build Action as "Content"
3. rpt file property :  Copy to Output Directory as "Do not Copy"
4. rpt file properties :  Put Empty for Custom Tool and Custom Tool Namespace

Put application is still raise the previous error .
can someone help me to fix this proplem

Answer (score 0):

Use runtime path for loadding report I.e
reportDocument.Load(Application.StartupPath + "\CrystalReport1.rpt");

Make sure report files are placed in specified folder which is directed by this path. use 
string str = Application.StartupPath;
to be sure that which folder it refers to then place report files in this folder it will work fine. I faced similar problem like you and then I noticed this path indicates to bin\debug folder while report files in my project were somewhere else I just copied all files to debug folder and its working fine .... cheers

Answer (score 0):

Crystal often gives you missleading error messages.

In my case I've set Copy to Output Directory of *.rpt file to "Do not Copy" (like you have it too) and I was passing the file path to the bin folder (where it doesn't exist) to ((ReportDocument)rpt).Load("[/bin/folder/path/report.rpt]");

**->So check if the file(path) you want to load really exist**

My Build Action is set to Embedded Resource (was default)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was a problem with permission. Check if all users are allowed to access the file.
   [image]